# mysqli_sql_exception unknown column in codeigniter when using findAll()

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am learning CodeIgniter4, and i got stuck while using function findAll(), it says this: mysqli_sql_exception #1054
Unknown column 'cursos.deleted_at' in 'where clause'

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Codigofacilito_model extends Model
{
  protected $table      = 'cursos';
  protected $primaryKey = 'idCurso';

  protected $returnType     = 'array';
  protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

  protected $allowedFields = ['nombreCurso','videosCurso'];

  protected $useTimestamps = false;
  protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
  protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
  protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

  protected $validationRules    = [];
  protected $validationMessages = [];
  protected $skipValidation     = false;

  function __construct()
  {
    if (is_callable('parent::__construct')) {
      parent::__construct();
    }
  }

  function crearCurso($arr)
  {
    $this->insert
    (array(
        'nombreCurso' => $arr['nombre'],
        'videosCurso' => $arr['videos']
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\codigofacilito_model;

class Cursos extends BaseController{
  function __construct(){
    if (is_callable('parent::__construct')) {
      parent::__construct();
    }
    helper('form');
  }

  function index(){
    $modelo1=new Codigofacilito_model($db);
    $data=$modelo1->findAll();
    echo view('codigofacilito/headers');
    echo view('cursos/cursos',$data);
  }

}
```

The connection is correct, and all the table names and others are correct.

Comment: Be sure to not use the __construct magic method in your controllers. Instead use the initController method provided in your BaseController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says you're missing the `deleted_at` column in your `cursos` table.

Here you told two major things to Codeigniter :

- With `protected $useSoftDeletes = true;` you're telling him : **I don't want to use SQL delete statement, instead update the `deleted_at` field**
  Note that `deleted_at` can either be a date format (format that you can specify with `$dateFormat` parameter in your model) or an
  INTEGER.
- With  `protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';`, you are setting the name of the field that will be used with soft deletes.

Your error is catched when calling `findAll()` method since the framework will filter the records to those that are not soft deleted, using the field name you provided him.

So if you want to resolve your error, either add `deleted_at` column in your table or change `$deletedField` value with your soft delete column that already exists.

For further informations about CI4 Model configuration : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#configuring-your-model

Also since you have the $useTimestamps = false you don't need to set a name for the created_at and updated_at.